# HTML & bootstrap/ text is override another table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in HTML, using bootstrap:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     <div class="container-fluid form-group" ng-repeat="app in allKeys track by $index">

         <label for="inputEmail2" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{app}}</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6 table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
             <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="app1 in allDesc[$index]"><b> {{app1}}</b> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr >
                 <td ng-repeat="app2 in allValues[$index]"> {{app2}} </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

I have two main problem:

1. If the text is too long in the label section (`{{app}}`), the text is continue in the line, and override the text in the table section.

[image]

2. If I minimize the browser windows, the container doesn't get the correct size.

[image]

I think that this issues are result of definition in the css, that should adjust the text to the appropriate size of the window/column, but I didn't find any css definition for that.

Comment: You forgot to close a div after </table>, I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: include text without any space this problem is occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your main problem is just a missing closing `<div>` tag. You haven't closed the `container-fluid`. You can see it working in [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VFppDX2Bsd#)

I also changed your `col-md-4` to `col-sm-4`, as your table wrapper was using `sm` definitions, which meant that your `label` would have broken to full width at 'medium' size and your table would have broken to full width at 'small' size, which caused some layout inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <div class="container-fluid form-group row" ng-repeat="app in allKeys track by $index">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <label for="inputEmail2" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{app}} </label></div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
         <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="app1 in allDesc[$index]"><b> {{app1}}</b> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr >
             <td ng-repeat="app2 in allValues[$index]"> {{app2}} </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

making the width to 100% and splitting the blocks accordingly, will help the browser to display the content in a proper way and remember to close the "div" whenever the content for the div is over. Else, the following content will go with misplacement.